# Is necessary show a prominent disclosure by popup about location (not background) permissions?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-permissions

One month ago Google Play Console rejected my latest update and said that it is not compliant with the location in the background policies.
More precisely, the google email reports " If your app is not eligible to access location in the background or does not meet requirements for accessing location in the background, please remove the permission from your manifest and in-app functionality."

I used the background location permission for scanning BLE in ionic app (https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central ).

I removed the background location permission (ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) from cordova plugin because, after some test, is effectively not really necessary. However, are necessary other location permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) so **I would like to know if is equally necessary to display a prominent disclosure through a pop-up alert before my app’s location runtime permission.**

I tried to send an issue ticket to google developer support on April 14th, but I have not received a reply.

Comment: Hi @Andrea , Can I know how you solve this? I am also facing a similar issue. Have you change the Prominent Disclosure Dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you target Android API version 28 or lower, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION implicitly implies background location permission and you must hence follow all the rules for that.

If you target Android API version 29 or higher and do not have ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in your manifest, you will automatically comply to Google Play's background policies (since you are then not affected by them).

Comment: Thanks Emil, it is an old app and the API version is 21 or higher, so as you mentioned, I will explicitly explain why background location is necessary. Google said that an example of frase could be: “This app collects location data to enable ["feature"], ["feature"], & ["feature"] even when the app is closed or not in use.” But is not really correct in my case, because I don't collect location data when the app is closed. I have some doubts on the right frase to insert in prominent disclosure...

Comment: I think this should not be an issue anymore now, since Google Play has started to force developers to target at least API 29. Hence you should not even be able to submit an app version targeting API 21.

Comment: Sorry for my eventual mistake, but if I have android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" on the manifest, does it mean that my target Android API version is 30 or lower (API version is 21 or higher)?

Comment: If you have targetSdkVersion=30, it means your app follows all the standards set up by API 30, but is backwards-compatible to devices all down to API 21, so that it works on Lollipop and up.